# Adding Cookie to Age Verification Popup

Tags: jquery, js-cookie

I am not very experienced in JavaScript or jQuery, but I have created an age verification popup. I need to add cookies to my "yes button" function so the popup doesn't show if a user visits within 7 days. Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/kp-marz/pen/xEyKYy)

I have researched enough to know I should be using js-cookie. Just no idea how to implement. This is as far as I have got.

```
<!--HTML-->
<div class="popup"> 
    <div class="popupWindow">
            <div class="popup_txt">
            <div class="row">
            <center><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" width="400px"></center>
            </div>
           <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #000;">
            <div class="row">
                    <h2>Where You Born Before</h2>
                    <h1 class="text-center"><span id="date"></span>?</h1>

            <div class="popup_img answer">
                    <button class="popup_img_yes btn btn-primary btn-lg">Yes</button>
                    <button class="popup_img_no btn btn-primary btn-lg">No</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
jQuery(".popup_img_yes").click(function(){
jQuery(".popup").fadeOut( 1200 ); });
});
```

I am guessing I need to use the following somehow:

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it could work:

```js
var Cookies2 = Cookies.noConflict();

$(".popup_img_yes").click(function() {
  $(".popup").fadeOut(1200);
  Cookies2.set('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });
});
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popupWindow">
    <div class="popup_txt">
      <div class="row">
        <center>
          <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" width="400px">
        </center>
      </div>
      <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #000;">
      <div class="row">
        <h2>Where You Born Before</h2>
        <h1 class="text-center"><span id="date"></span>?</h1>

        <div class="popup_img answer">
          <button class="popup_img_yes btn btn-primary btn-lg">Yes</button>
          <button class="popup_img_no btn btn-primary btn-lg">No</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/master/src/js.cookie.js"></script>
```